# set cors rules for azure storage through terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cli

I've been looking online and I can't seem to find a way of setting the cors rules through terraform.

I don't believe it is supported yet in terraform.

It is possible to set the CORS rules through the az cli:

```
azure storage cors set --blob static 
--cors "[{\"AllowedOrigins\":\"*\",\"AllowedMethods\":\"GET\",\"MaxAgeInSeconds\":\"86400\",\"AllowedHeaders\":\"*\",\"ExposedHeaders\":\"*\"}]"
-a "account-name" -k "account-key" --verbose
```

Can I shell out from terraform to call this or is there a way of tying them together?

Comment: It seems you use the classic module and Terraform support the ARM module. You can try to use the ARM, it's recommended.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else comes across this and would like to avoid the horror of the azure arm template then this was my fix as there is nothing in terraform at this time of writing:

```
resource "null_resource" "storage" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az storage cors clear --account-name ${azurerm_storage_account.main.name} --services b"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az storage cors add --account-name ${azurerm_storage_account.main.name} --origins '*' --methods GET POST PUT --allowed-headers 'Accept-Ranges,Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,x-ms-blob-content-type,x-ms-blob-type,x-ms-version' --exposed-headers 'Accept-Ranges,Content-Range,Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Type' --max-age 86400 --services b"
  }
}
```

I am having to call `az storage cors clear` or else new rules get created each time it runs.

Comment: I confirm that this works well. For reference, here is the issue tracking the native support of CORS configuration for Azure Blob in Terraform: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/19

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with Terraform ([proof](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_account.html)). You can use ARM templates as mentioned or just a script resource in Terraform via a provisioner to do that for you (Azure CLI, like you mention).

example ARM template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "name": "[concat('storage', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "accountType": "Standard_LRS",
        "cors": {
          "allowedHeaders": [ "*" ],
          "allowedMethods": [ "get", "post", "put" ],
          "allowedOrigins": [ "*" ],
          "exposedHeaders": [ "*" ],
          "maximumAge": 5
        },
        "val": "123"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you stop calling it `crappyform`? It's unnecessary. Also this answer is barely more than a comment right now and doesn't offer any more than the previous answer does.

Comment: this answer proves that this is not possible with cf, compared to the other answer that offers no explanation

Comment: That's barely more useful at all and you should know better than that at 30k rep. Either edit your answer to make it genuinely better than the existing one or remove it.

Comment: that's a solid proof, compared to a speculation. if that is barely more useful. okay. I guess you are special in this case

Comment: I'm curious to know why you called it crappyform

Comment: your question is one of the endless reasons it is ;)

Comment: is there any better, I don't want to learn aws and azure configuration.  arm templates are nasty.

Comment: cf doesnt help you in anyway with that. you still have to learn and understand azure and aws configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a resource template and apply that template with Terraform.

[Configure CORS by using Azure Resource Manager template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173859/configure-cors-by-using-azure-resource-manager-template)

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by adding an example inline to the answer.

Comment: yes please, I'm still unsure how I would do this for storage

Comment: I'm also on bash and not powershell